# hide an inputfield?

Tags: php, html, hide

i have an input field which will be displayed. i want that to hide when a variable from my php script is set.

i would like to know if that is possible. i know there is a way with

```
<input type="hidden">
```

but like i know there is just javascript to make this field visible. so i ask for other way round.

i have

```
<input type="text">
```

and would like to hide it with

```
<?php if(isset($var) && $var =="1"):?>
```

is there a way to realize that? thanks alot.

okay what i was looking for is:

```
<input type="<?php echo ($var === '1' ? 'hidden' : 'text'); ?>">
```

that is exactly what i need. another question: is there a way to implement that to a select option field? thanks.

Comment: Do you want it hidden just fromt the normal UI, or do you want it so that it can't be seen if someone views the source?  If it's the former, you can just use javascript to set the item's Display css style property:  [input item name].style.display = none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

If `$var` is `=` to `1` then set type attribute to hidden.

```
<input type="<?php echo ($var === '1' ? 'hidden' : 'text'); ?>">
```

**Update:**

```
Bad: <select style="display: <?php echo ($var === '1' ? 'hidden' : 'inline'); ?>;">
Good: <select style="display: <?php echo ($var === '1' ? 'none' : 'inline'); ?>;">
```

Comment: thats it. it works like it should do. thanks alot. one more question: is there a similiar for a select option field?

Comment: Added a select example as well using inline CSS.

Comment: this does not work :( it will display the select field in both cases ->var=0 and var=1

Comment: you mean:   <select style="display:none <?php echo ($var === '1' ? 'none' : 'inline'); ?>;">   ? this does not work.

Comment: No. I changed my example above. Use that.

Comment: where? i dont see any changes?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript and/or css styles to set the input to `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`.

`<input type="text" class="<?=isset($var)&&$var==1?'hidden':''?>" />`

```
input[type=text].hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: i'm looking for a way without javascript.

Comment: If you use PHP to determine if the type should be hidden or text, it would be more difficult to change that afterwards in the browser. Use styles to achieve what you want and in the future you can easily make the hidden attribute dynamically changeable, revealing the input if the users actions would deem that appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when this field needs to be hidden. Does it depend on when the user enter info into that field? (Java script, `Document.getElementById('field_id').style('display:none');`). Or if you know you need to hide this before loading of the page. (PHP `<input type="<?=(isset($var) && $var =="1") ? "hidden" : "text";?>" />`)

For the Javascript portion, I assume you do not have JQuery or other JS framework, else the syntax would be much simplier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input <?php if(isset($var) && $var =="1") echo "type=\"hidden\""; else echo "type=\"text\""; ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `display: none;` for css class and can switch through javascript or so.

Answer (score 0):

I have not DreamWeaver where i can test it. But i can tell u logic for this. You can take a common string variable as you declare in php like

CommonVariable="Hidden"

and assign it to

And change when your condition true.

CommonVariable="text"